# Python Serial Communication with Mbed

Tags: python, pyserial, mbed

```
import serial
while True:
device = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0')
data = device.readline()
print(data + '\n')
```

I have a device that communicates to a raspberry pi using USB port and pyserial in python. What should I do so that when user inputs "reset" on the command line the device will be reset?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but you would need to create some handler code on the device that calls `NVIC_SystemReset()` whenever it sees `reset` come in over the serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what "a device" means. Assuming the device is an Mbed device connected to the Raspberry pi and your Python code is running on the Raspberry pi.

Most Mbed devices can be reset by sending BREAK condition on the serial interface. Check pySerial API for this https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.send_break

Also, check how it is done in this tool for Python 2.7 and 3.x https://github.com/ARMmbed/htrun/blob/master/mbed_host_tests/host_tests_plugins/module_reset_mbed.py#L60